# Show form if input field has data or else dont show

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am dynamically adding text to the input field from facebook signup data, and then populating these data to the form field which has a `display:none` property. After getting all the data the form should show as in `display:block`. But that is not working. the code seems to be working on console but not on the browser.

I am checking if the input field is filled then show the form or else no.

Here is the jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/kqHmR/1/

```
if ($("#firstname").val() == $("#firstname").val(dataCollection.first_name)) {
    $("#profileEdit").hide();
} else {
    $("#profileEdit").show();
}
```

What is wrong with it? It is supposed to show me the form when there is something in the input fields but it's not showing .

Comment: Shouldnt you be using `===` for the equality check?

Comment: One thing: '$("#firstname").val(dataCollection.first_name)' means that you set a value, while '$("#firstname").val()' means read a value from given element.

Comment: @shishirmk it isn't nessecary.

Comment: @reporter true I hadnt noticed the bigger problem with the comparison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you just check if `dataCollection.first_name` is empty?

Here's a one-liner

```
$("#profileEdit").toggle(dataCollection.first_name.length);
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Explanation: `.toggle()` can accept a boolean. true = show, false = hide.

If a string's .length is zero, it evaluates to false, thus passing false into `.toggle()`. Vice versa.

---

In case you *really* want to check the input field's value instead, then:

```
$("#profileEdit").toggle( $.trim( $("#firstname").val() ).length );
```

Translated in English would be: *Get me the value of firstname, trim it, and give me the length of that string, then pass it into `.toggle()`*

Answer (score 0):

`.val()` when called with an argument, sets the value and **returns the jQuery object** it was called on (to facilitate chaining). It *does not return the value* as such, unlike when called without arguments.

This means your if condition

```
if ($("#firstname").val() == $("#firstname").val(dataCollection.first_name)) {
```

will always fail as the RHS is *not the newly set value* but the jQuery object `$("#firstname")` itself.

Comment: Yeah this is the reason i guess it was failing.